# Best practice for build up a server for database

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

Currently, I have a window application with using SQL 2008 R2.

This application is used by 200 users at the same time.

The database's size is almost 20gb.

The db server uses 16gb RAM, 200gb HDD.

And server is slow now, the CPU is over 80%, RAM was configured 14gb limit.

Does anyone have a tool or best practice to find out why the server is slow down?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: Hire a DBA

Comment: You should try posting this in dba.stackexchange.com (but you should try a tool like the First Responder Kit https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/ first, so that you have some useful information in your question).

Comment: When I see 'HDD' (singular) and '200 concurrent users' I can't but assume that you PROBABLY have an I/O issue. That said, I have no clue what your application is about so it might well be that it's all read-only and fully served from memory... If not, check sys.dm_os_wait_stats during busy hours and see if your IO subsystem might be the cause for long waits. Alternatively you could set up a profiler to log all statements that take more than a couple of seconds. Again, I don't have a clue about your application; looking into an OLTP is rather different than looking into a DWH.